# The best model not getting saved even after adding Callbacks

Tags: keras

Despite following the suggested steps to save the best model by adding callbacks to model.fit, the h5 file is not getting saved. 
Rest of the stuff like epochs are running well.

```
# fit model
callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10),
             ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.h5', 
             monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, epochs=300,callbacks=callbacks,verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=128, validation_split=0.1, 
                 epochs=300,callbacks=callbacks,verbose=1)
```

**Mistake:** Your `ModelCheckpoint` is based on the `val_loss` i.e every time it finds a better (minimum in this case) validation loss it saves the model. However, when you are fitting the model you are not passing any data for validation. Which mean no validation loss is calcuated and so no model is saved.

In the above code `validation_split=0.1` useses 10% of `(X, y)` as validation data.

Also note that the other callback `EarlyStopping` is also based on `val_loss`, so without validation data it will not do early stopping. So either manually pass the validation data to `fit` method or use a random split of `(X, y)` as validation data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realized that without validation data, I'm monitoring val_loss as you suggested.

Are there any alternatives to saving the best model during training phase (without validation data) ?

Comment: @KishoreSuren yes you can instead use `loss` as monitor which will use the train loss. However it is not recommended as it will lead to over fitting to train data. As as rule of thumb train on train data and measure the performance on validation data.  Spare 10% of your train data as validation data using `validation_split=0.1`. If your data is very less then use Kfold cross validation. However if you still dont want to use validataion data you can change your monitor to `loss`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @KishoreSuren glad it helped :) Welcome to SO. If your question is answered please accept the answer for conclusion (only and only if it answered your question ). [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I'm apparently not reputed enough to do so. This was the error : 'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.' 
:D